# attach image to sagemaker import fail

Tags: dockerfile, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

Created a docker image that was deployed to AWS ERC and later attached to AWS SageMaker. When I open a jupyter notebook on SageMaker and Change the kernel image I choose the newly attached image. The issue is that when I do a simple import of one of the libraries that was included I find that it fails because it does not exist.

After multiple looking around I found various possible solutions but none have work.

When I do `sys.executable` I get the following directory `/opt/.sagemakerinternatl/conda/bin/python`.

If I do the same for a pre-built SageMaker image I get the following directory `ur/local/bin/python`

Is this the issue?

Another thing I tried was creating my dockerfile with a virtual environment where I installed all dependencies but that hasn't work yet.

Anything I should be looking to solve this problem, would be greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Could be something to do with how the image was built and added to sagemaker studio. Please refer to this blog which gives you instructions to add a customer kernel.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/bringing-your-own-custom-container-image-to-amazon-sagemaker-studio-notebooks/